# Android doesn't launch my emulator, it says that is already running or delete file in a certain directory

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

When I try to launch my emulator it display an error that says: "Emulator is already running", but my emulator isn't running. So it also say: "
If that is not the case, delete the files at
C:\Users\MYUSER.android\avd/Pixel_4_API_30.avd/*.lock"
But  I can't find this directory.
Anyone can help me?

Comment: Just close your `Android Studio` and `Open Again`. It always works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this you need first to **delete** the *.lock folder that has a path printed to you in your running log.

Then, cold boot for the device:

1. Go to AVD Manager

[image]

2. Press on "Cold Boot Now"

[image]

Comment: Forcing the cold boot worked, thank you

Comment: Great! YOU ARE WELCOME.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when your emulator didn't shutdown properly while running emulator it create .lock extension for running your emulator just go to your avd location in your system

C:\Users\bizap.android\avd\Pixel_3a_API_30_Nitin_.avd (this is my avd location) and from here delete .lock extension file after that try to re run your emulator.. it will work for location.

Open your adv manager after opening you will see your emulator on the right side of emulator you will find green drop down arrow after click on that arrow pop up menu open and then select show on disk option when you click on show on disk it will redirect you to avd location.